# Unable to customize AppTheme for action bar in Android app

Tags: android, android-theme

I'm trying to customize the action bar. I've done it before too, but I'm unable to do it now. Not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_gradient</item>
</style>
```

This is the drawable that I'm adding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:startColor="#d6ece542"
        android:endColor="#fffffdf4"
        />
</shape>
```

I've also added this inside `<application>` tag in my manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

But every time I'm just getting the same action-bar (the default of the theme). Can someone tell what's wrong?

Also FYI, my minSdk version=18, and target version=21

Comment: make sure you are adding  `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` to `<activity>` tag of manifest file.

Comment: @Apurva: I want to apply the theme over the entire application hence I've already added that line inside the <application> tag. 
I've done this before on other projects too, not sure what is happening differently here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to apply a Holo action bar theme to a Material AppCompat theme.

**One solution is to apply the gradient as the `colorPrimary`:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@drawable/actionbar_gradient</item>
</style>
```

More customization attributes: https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#StatusBar

**Another solution would be to just switch to the Holo theme:**

1. Change your activity to `extends Activity`
2. Change your parent theme to `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`

Comment: I didn't understand how you got that assumption. But the fact is that I can't change it to what you said because that needs minimum to be API level 21. Mine is 18.
So I'm not using the material theme in the first place.

Comment: You are using app compat for v21, which is material design. What exactly requires v21? Your comment is too vague for me to respond to.

Comment: If you're referring to the link, that is not using the appcompat library. If you use the appcompat library, the attributes are not `android:` namespaced. I just wanted to include that image.

Comment: My minSdkVersion 18 and targetSdkVersion 21, so I was getting an error that my minimum version needs to be 21. 
But there was an override option, which created a styles.xml (v21) file. After I applied my theme to that the theme was visible in cardview (when I see all my stacked apps), but not on viewing the app itself

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. My gradient was using transparent colours, so when I was trying your method I was encountering errors. Could you please edit this detail in your answer?
Thank you

Comment: I still don't follow. The first solution is good as far back as v7. The second is good back to v11~v14 depending on your action bar theme parent. If you have an edit, feel free to submit it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add `android:type="linear"` to that gradient definition

```
<gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:startColor="#d6ece542"
    android:endColor="#fffffdf4"
    android:type="linear"
    />
```

Comment: I'm sorry but that didn't help